# Yet another matrix equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations

> Solve the following matrix equation for $X$.
>
> $$\left[\begin{array}{cc}
> 5 &-8\cr
> 8 &1
> \end{array}\right] X + \left[\begin{array}{cc}
> 6 &6\cr
> 3 &5
> \end{array}\right] = \left[\begin{array}{cc}
> -1 &4\cr
> -3 &-1
> \end{array}\right] X$$

Please give me some hint to do this question. Thanks.

Comment: How would you solve the scalar equation $ax+b=cx$ for $x$? The same ideas apply here.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your matrix equation is $$ AX+B=CX$$

You solve for X.

$$(A-C)X=-B$$

$$X=-(A-C)^{-1}B$$
$$X=
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
-6 &12\cr
-11 &-2
\end{array}\right]^{-1}\left[\begin{array}{cc}
6 &6\cr
3 &5
\end{array}\right]$$

$$ X = \frac{1}{12}\left[\begin{array}{cc}
-4 & -6\cr
4 &3
\end{array}\right]$$

Answer (score 8):

This is a linear equation in four variables.

Let $X = \begin{bmatrix} x_{11} & x_{12} \\ x_{21} & x_{22} \end{bmatrix}$.

Consider each entry of the RHS and LHS as a seperate equation:

$$\begin{align}
5x_{11} - 8x_{21} + 6 &= -1x_{11}+4x_{12} & \text{(top left entry)}\\
5x_{12} - 8x_{22} + 6 &= -1x_{12}+4x_{22} & \text{(top right entry)}\\
8x_{11} - 1x_{21} + 3 &= -3x_{11}-1x_{12} & \text{(bottom left entry)}\\
8x_{12} - 1x_{22} + 5 &= -3x_{12}-1x_{22} & \text{(bottom right entry)}\\
\end{align}$$

Now you get a linear system of four equations wich can be solved using the usual methods.

---

As an alternative you can directly use matrix operations and solve

$$\left[\begin{array}{cc}
5 &-8\cr
8 &1
\end{array}\right] X + \left[\begin{array}{cc}
6 &6\cr
3 &5
\end{array}\right] = \left[\begin{array}{cc}
-1 &4\cr
-3 &-1
\end{array}\right] X$$

iff

$$\left[\begin{array}{cc}
6 &6\cr
3 &5
\end{array}\right] = \left[\begin{array}{cc}
-1 &4\cr
-3 &-1
\end{array}\right] X - \left[\begin{array}{cc}
5 &-8\cr
8 &1
\end{array}\right] X  =\left[\begin{array}{cc}
-6 &12\cr
-11 &-2
\end{array}\right]X $$

iff

$$\left[\begin{array}{cc}
-6 &12\cr
-11 &-2
\end{array}\right]^{-1}\left[\begin{array}{cc}
6 &6\cr
3 &5
\end{array}\right] =X $$

(Note that the matrix that we are trying to invert is actually invertible since its determinant is $(-6)(-2)-(-11)12 = 144 \neq 0$.)

iff

$$X = \frac{1}{12}\left[\begin{array}{cc}
-4 & -6\cr
4 &3
\end{array}\right] $$

Comment: it should be $$ X = \frac{1}{12}\left[\begin{array}{cc}
-4 & -6\cr
4 &3
\end{array}\right]$$, thanks.